# Exception when 2 objects are instantiating each other

Tags: java, object, exception

So I'm creating a simple text based game but I came up with an exception/error along the way.
I have 3 classes one is a class called Main, one is a class called Mage, and one is a class called Warrior.

So in a game when a player uses an abbility it reduces the health points of the other player by a certant amount.

So when an abbility is used by player1 for example in this case Fireball it calls the method reduceHP in Warrior class which reduces the HP of player2 by 44. The method reduceHP takes the number that is passed in and substracts it from the health points of the player.

```
Warrior player2 = new Warrior();

public void FireBall(){

player2.reduceHP(44);

}
```

The same thing happens in Mage class. When the player1 uses a Warrior abbility it reduces the HP of player2 by 65.

```
Mage player1 = new Mage();

public void Stab(){

player1.reduceHP(65);


}
```

Now the problem is when I call these abbility/abbilities (stab and fireball) in the main class i get the following error

```
at Warrior.<init>(Warrior.java:4)
at Mage.<init>(Mage.java:4)
at Warrior.<init>(Warrior.java:4)
at Mage.<init>(Mage.java:4)
at Warrior.<init>(Warrior.java:4)
at Mage.<init>(Mage.java:4)
at Warrior.<init>(Warrior.java:4)
at Mage.<init>(Mage.java:4)
at Warrior.<init>(Warrior.java:4)
at Mage.<init>(Mage.java:4)
at Warrior.<init>(Warrior.java:4)
at Mage.<init>(Mage.java:4)
at Warrior.<init>(Warrior.java:4)

ETC... it keeps on going
```

I'm wondering why does this happen ? If there is another way of doing this please let me know since I'm quite new to java. Thanks for all the help it is much appreciated and I hope this is not a really dumb question to ask on here.

Comment: Add the complete classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instantiate the players in your `Main` class and then pass references to them by setter. This way you will have one instance of each object and they will have references to each other.

Comment: Oh alright I see what you mean ! One more question though which has nothing to do with this question. If I instantiate for example Warrior class in my Mage class how come that I can only use methods from Warrior class if I use the reference variable in a method. If I use the reference variable anywhere else and I try accessing Warrior class and methods/variables that are located in that class nothing comes up ?

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments. Create new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

The two fields `player1` and `player2` are the issue. I think you want to have exactly two objects, one for Player 1 and one for Player 2. Instead, you are creating an infinite number of objects inside the (implicit) constructors.

I guess you're a beginner, so I will not discuss the details here. To solve the issue, you might want to create a third class (maybe named `Game`?) which knows about the two players.